# Nodejs request parse special characters

Tags: node.js, string, html-parsing, special-characters

I'm using the nodejs request module to get some HTML of a website.

There are special characters in the HTML code of the website, which can't be parsed by node request.

For example: `ä ü` or `ö` will be parsed to `�`

So if theres a username like `Ämilia` its `�milia`

My basically looks like this:

```
const request = require("request");

let link = hidden_link;
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);
const response = await requestPromise(link);
console.log(response.body) // unparsed special chars here
```

Is there an easy node.js way to parse special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use an encoding parameter:

```
const request = require("request");

let link = hidden_link;
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);
const response = await requestPromise({ encoding: "latin1", url: link });
console.log(respone.body);
```